# trouble passing user-generated values as arguments to function using the arguments object

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

Using a textbox, I need for users to be able to be able to enter the numbers they'd like to find the average of, with each number separated by a space.

Here is the HTML for the textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="average" onchange="findAverage()" />
```

I know I need to use the arguments object to get the average.

From here, I get pretty lost.  It seems like maybe I should first convert the textbox input into an array, splitting on " " ? I am so seriously lost and would appreciate any help on this! The function I've got so far is below:

```
function findAverage(nums) {
  nums = document.getElementById("average").value;
  nums = nums.split(" ");

  for (var i=0, total = 0, len=arguments.length; i<len; i++) {
    total += arguments[i]; 
  } 
  document.getElementById("averageReturn").innerHTML = total / arguments.length;   
}
```

I've been reading everything I can find on using the arguments object and I really am not understanding it.

(If anyone can think of a better way of asking this, please feel free to edit this question to make it better/clearer for other users down the line!)

Comment: Why are you passing `nums` as the first argument then immediately writing over it and never using it again?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: Otherwise, you have the right idea. Don't pass `nums` as an argument and use `nums` in your `for` loop instead of the `arguments`. No reason to mix the two.

Comment: Ahh Mike, so I don't specify any arguments, just  findAverage(), I define nums in the for loop?

Comment: *"I know I need to use the arguments object to get the average."* You only have to use `arguments` if you are actually passing a variable number of arguments to the function. But you are not passing any arguments.

Comment: Yes, but I need to be passing a variable number of arguments and that is where I am utterly lost.  Users should be able to enter any number of numbers ...

Comment: `arguments` lets you refer to the arguments passed to the *function*. This has nothing to do with the *value* of the input element. `foo()` passes no arguments to `foo`, so inside `foo`, `arguments.length` is `0`. What *you* want is reading the value of the input, which you already do with `document.getElementById("average").value;`. Again, this has nothing to do with the parameters passed to the function. Maybe this helps to get a better understanding of functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html .

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you've hit the problem on the head.  I NEED to be passing the numbers a user enters in the textbox as arguments into a function using arguments objects to find the average. I can't figure out how to pass those user-generated numbers as arguments.

Comment: *Why* do you need to do that? You are already getting the numbers with `nums = document.getElementById("average").value;`. Why do you want to pass them as arguments? Why can't you just use `nums`?

Comment: @FelixKling because life, the universe and my professor are unfair...

Answer (score 2):

Your solution isn't far off, but you are making your life difficult by using the `onchange` HTML attribute. Neither the `arguments` local variable nor the `nums` argument have any relevance in your case.

I would instead use the `addEventListener` method. This is both easier to read, and makes it trivial to get ahold of the input's value when it is changed. Something like this ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lQPwa9jPjneTEl58ttli?p=preview)):

```
function findAverage() {
  // grab the value, split on whitespace, parse into numbers
  var nums = this.value.split(' ').map(parseFloat);

  // compute total
  for (var i = 0, total = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
    total += nums[i];
  }

  // compute average and write to output element
  document.getElementById("averageReturn").innerHTML = total / len;
}

// add change listener
document
  .getElementById('average')
  .addEventListener('change', findAverage, false);
```

Notice that when `findAverage` is bound using `addEventListener`, inside the function, `this` refers to the target element, and `this.value` holds the current value of that element.

Answer (score 0):

Hello after reading the comments:

`<input type="text" id="average" onchange="findAverage(this.value)" />`

is what you wanted.

---

The two problems I see in your code are:

1. you are using `arguments` instead of `nums`. `nums` is the array of numbers you've created. FYI `arguments` in a javascript function is an object containing all the arguments.
2. The split result of `nums.split(" ");` is an array of strings. you may want to use `Number()`

Comment: I recommend to use `Number` instead of `parseInt`.

Comment: You guys have been so very helpful.  The quandry I'm in is that it is required that I use an arguments object function to achieve this.  There must be a way to pass the numbers the user enters in the box as arguments into the function.

Comment: Hello if you use the above code then arguments [0] will be the string you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions offered above were good but didn't completely solve the issue.  The missing component that allows the user-generated values to be passed as arguments was the apply() function.  The apply function lets you use array literals as parameters. Here is the working solution

```
function findAverage2() {
    //code
    nums = document.getElementById("average").value;
    nums = nums.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      nums[i] =parseInt(nums[i]);
    }
    //With apply, you can use an array literal as parameter arguments
    findAverage.apply(null, nums);   
  }
```